# Potential side-effects associated with a dash in a package/class name?

Tags: packages, best-practices, document-classes

Common practice for naming packages and classes seems to be, using regex-like notation:

```
[a-z][a-z0-9]*
```

In other words, the name usually starts by a lowercase letter, followed by any sequence of lowercase letters and digits.

However, some packages (e.g. `tikz-3dplot`) and classes (e.g. `revtex4-1`) contain a `-` in their name. I am myself tempted to use a dash in the name of one of my packages. Is that wise?  Aside from perhaps inconveniencing some users by deviating from naming conventions...

... **Are there potential side-effects associated with using a dash in a package/class name?**

Comment: should be OK: any normal ascii value, main thing to watch out for is punctuation characters that babel uses for shorthands, although mostly babel does that after begin{document} these days so should not affect package names.

Comment: syntax highlighting might be off

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be OK: any normal ASCII value. The main thing to watch out for is punctuation characters that babel uses for shorthands, although mostly `babel` does that after `\begin{document}` these days so even those should not affect package names.

Also avoid characters that are special in the underlying `kpathsea` library for example `"` is used to delimit files with spaces in their names and optionally file names starting `|` are treated as a shell command to execute. It's probably best to avoid those.

Finally, avoid spaces or commas as they would seriously mess up the `\usepackage` parsing. You can input a file called `array,longtable.sty` into TeX but `\usepackage{array,longtable}` isn't going to work.